# Get String of concatenated Enum long values using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an Enum with int values:

```
public enum Enum{
    ONE(1) ,
    TWO(2) ,
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4) ;

    private final long id;

    Enum(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I am trying to print the ids of all enum in a string using java stream. Something like this:

```
String ids = Stream.of(Enum.values())
                   .map(value -> value.getId())
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(",");
```

I tried `mapToObj` and boxed but my IDE doesn't recognize it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should map to a `String` before collecting to a `String`:

```
String ids = Stream.of(Enum.values())
        .map(value -> String.valueOf(value.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method in `Enum` to return the string value of your id.

```java
public String getIdValue() {
    return String.valueOf(this.id);
}
```

`Collectors.joining` expects a stream of `String`, but you are currently passing a stream of long.

```java
return Stream.of(Enum.values())
             .map(Enum::getIdValue)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(",");
```